# AJAX request to Vimeo API - 401 Unauthorized - Invalid API Key - The API key passed was not valid

Tags: jquery, oauth, vimeo

I am tring to explore VIMEO API and I am trying to make a request to VIMEO in order to search videos by tag.

I am failing on the first step because I am not able to get the requested toquen which would allow me to authenticate my account as an user and be able to do the search. I am following the vimeo documentation - http://vimeo.com/api/docs/oauth

However, it seems that my request fails.

The ajax call I am using is as follow:

```
    $.ajax({
        url:'http://vimeo.com/oauth/request_token?format=jsonp&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvimeo.com%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob&%26oauth_consumer_key%3D233b065ffd1268d5ae708255c9274499&%26oauth_nonce%3Dabcdefghijk&%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1&%26oauth_timestamp%3D1234567890&%26oauth_version%3D1.0%26oauth_consumer_key%3D25413c9038fa2fd7&callback=?',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#output').text(JSON.stringify(data));
        },
        error: function(errorSender, errorMsg) {
            $('#output').text(errorSender + '' +errorMsg);
        }
    });
```

The error give it in the console is:
401 Unauthorized - Invalid API Key - The API key passed was not valid

Has anyone experienced the same problem? Please help!

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a really old post. I thinks it using v1. Vimeo v2 is out now. The code for that is completely different but the pain in getting it working is the same.